# Datepicker (or other) widget with close "x" button: delete choosen values?

Tags: forms, buttons, web-app, input-fields, close

I have a complex search form with some fields to fill out for a search over products. 
Some of them are fake fields and open widgets (like the jquery UI datepicker widget etc).

I tweaked the standard datepicker's behaviour, so it doesn't close on selecting a date, but with a confirm button underneath.

My question is, if I'd add a closing "x" in the top right corner, how should it behave.
I read that a closing "x" isn't the same as an explicit "Cancel" button.

Should chosen values be deleted (set back to former values)? 
Or does it close the widget, but also adds the date to the main search form, just like the accept/choose button?

Answer (score 1):

You must have a clearly marked exit (Jakob Nielsen - Usability Engineering). You should have two buttons labeled "OK" and "Cancel". Do NOT add an "X", to avoid confusion.